# Compare sizes of vectors in a vector to get the largest

Tags: c++

How do I compare sizes of vectors that are stored in a vector to get the LARGEST one?

Let's say I have 5 vectors of ints of various sizes(some may have the same size). Actually, in my game there will likely be a few hundred vectors of integers.

```
vector <int> v1;
vector <int> v2;
vector <int> v3;
vector <int> v4;
vector <int> v5;
```

I have a vector that stores the 5 vectors of ints above

```
vector <vector <int> > vAllvects;
```

I'm able to cout the sizes of the 5 vectors that the vAllvects vector stores

```
for(vector < vector < int >  > :: size_type  iter  =  0;  iter  <  vAllvects.size() ; iter++ )
{
    cout  <<  " vAllvects["  << iter << "]  size  is  " <<  vAllvects[iter].size()  << endl ;

    for(vector < vector < int >  > :: size_type  x =  0;  x <  v. Allvects[iter].size() ; x++)
    {
    }
    cout  << endl;
}
```

What I need is the vector or vectors with the greatest size.

How do I compare each vector size in each element of the vAllvects vector to get the vector or vectors of greatest size?

Answer (score 4):

There are usually standard library algorithms for this kind of thing. In this case, you can use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) with a suitable binary predicate:

```
auto max_iterator = std::max_element(std::begin(vAllvects),
                                     std::end(vAllvects),
                                     [](const std::vector<int>& lhs,
                                        const std::vector<int>& rhs)
                                     {
                                       return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
                                     });
```

Here, `max_iterator` it an iterator to largest vector, or the first one of them if more than one have the largest size.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the vector containing the vectors, keeping track of the largest one through e.g. a pointer. For example:

```
unsigned int largestSize = 0;
vector<int>* largestVect = 0;

for(unsigned int i=0; i<vAllvects.size(); ++i) {
    if(vAllvects[i].size() > largestSize) {
        largestSize = vAllvects[i].size();
        largestVect = &vAllvects[i];
    }
}
```

Now you have a pointer to the largest vector.

Comment: Thanks,I thought a pointer would work,but i did'nt know how to implement it.

Comment: While the pointer does work ,Its crucial that i get all the vectors of that largest size,not just the very first one ! Because under some conditions one vector may be choosen,and under other conditions a different one could be choosen.